# Create all posible variations of string Python

Tags: python, string, character, swap

I'm totally new to python but have to do some tasks using this language. The task is to create all possible variations (swapping characters in the string). My string has 2 parts: left and right, separated by '>='. So I need to change only the left part. String example is below:
`ab>=c`. So the task is to get string `ba>=c` (Due to task these strings are equal)
Example with more characters:

`abc>=d , acb>=d , bac>=d , bca>=d , cab>=d , cba>=d`

I would appreciate any help. Task seems to be pretty easy, but I have some problems with python things

Comment: You might want to add what you have tried already and what problems in your process you run into. Users here generally like to help you understand your problems, but not really doing your work for you.... Of course it's different if you have no clue about how to tackle your problem in the frist place, but then your problem is not the programming language.

Comment: Do you want to get the left side of the text and replace it with another text?

Comment: @Nima I'm going to add all these possible variations to one list. But I need at least the right way to do this 'swaps'

Comment: @Andre I'm not asking for full code (of course, that will be fine, but anyway). I'm looking for some better way for doing this, maybe some functions that I don't know in python, or any existing algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **itertools** library can help you
**Shortcode**

```
from itertools import permutations
perms = [''.join(i) for i in permutations('abc')] # all possible string
# perms == ['abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

**Expanded code**

```
perms=[]
for i in permutations('abc'):
    # i == ('a','b','c')
    perms+=[''.join(i)] # 'abc'
```